# Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityLoginBinding' in androidstudio Java class

Tags: java, android-studio

import org.srujan.stepoutv01.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
private ActivityLoginBinding binding;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
            .get(LoginViewModel.class);

    final EditText usernameEditText = binding.email;
    final EditText passwordEditText = binding.password;[enter image description here][1]
    final Button loginButton = binding.login;
    final ProgressBar loadingProgressBar = binding.loading;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the below code in your build.gradle(:app) file?

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
```

If not, Just add these above lines before `buildTypes` like below

```
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

If the problem is the same, Just go to `Build`>`Clean Project`. Works fine. Let me know if the problem is not solved.